# Next JS Slug Page won work on vercel deployment

Tags: next.js, vercel

I made a website with NextJS and deployed it on Vercel.

From url: https://etiselektrik.vercel.app/teknikbilgi/ if i click the first article. The page loads without any problem.
However if i directly enter the url with the slug page: https://etiselektrik.vercel.app/teknikbilgi/reaktifenerji-reaktifceza I get 500 internal server error.

I dont have this error in my production build.

Here is my code for the slug page:

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import { API_URL } from '../../config/index';

export default function BlogPost({ post }) {
return (
    <Layout
      title={post.title}
      description={post.metaDescription}
      keywords={post.metaKeywords}
    >
      <h1 className='px-4 py-4 md: my-4 simpleContainer font-semibold text-2xl text-secondary text-left'>
        {post.title}
      </h1>
      <div className='px-4 simpleContainer text-secondary'>
        {ReactHtmlParser(post.content)}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { slug } }) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/teknikbilgis/${slug}`);
    const post = await res.json();

    return {
      props: {
        post: post,
      },
    };
  } catch {
    return {
      props: {
        post: {},
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: your slugs are different. The one in the app doesn't have "-" while yours does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. On the client side, i used .replaceAll function to change my post before parsing. (I didnt add them in my code as i thought it was irrelevant)

.replaceAll() seems to cause problems in nextjs on deployment. I changed it to .replace() Now it works.